# Кодировка при парсинге картинок с jsoup

Tags: java, android, парсер, jsoup

Привет! Пытаюсь парсить картинки из ссылки, там периодически попадается нечто типа

```html
<img src="http://dog.org/sites/default/files/images/ главной!.thumbnail.jpg">
```

.

```
 class ParsePage extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{
    Document doc=null;
    Elements names,imgs;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            input = new URL("http://vao-priut.org/category/fotokatalog/sektor");
            String link = String.valueOf(input);

                doc = Jsoup.connect(link).get();
                names = doc.select("table.col-3 div.views-field-title span.field-content a[href]");
                imgs = doc.select("table.col-3 div.views-field-image-image span.field-content a img");


                for (Element img : imgs) {

                    Element myImage = img;
                    String imgSrc = myImage.attr("src");
                    InputStream inp = new java.net.URL(imgSrc).openStream();
                    // Decode Bitmap
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inp);

                    allImages.add(bitmap);
                }
                for (Element name : names) {
                    list.add(name.text());
                }
           /* ProgressDialog mDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            mDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            mDialog.setCancelable(false);
            mDialog.show();*/


            }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return text;
        }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        sectorAdapter = new sector_adapter(getActivity());
        c_grid.setAdapter(sectorAdapter);
        image.setImageBitmap(allImages.get(0));
       title.setText(list.get(0));






    }
}
```

Как исправить данную проблему?

В зависимости от ссылки выдает либо:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

либо:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] тут ругается на пробел

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
String input = new URL("http://vao-priut.org/category/fotokatalog/sektor");
InputStream input = new URL(url).openStream();
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "CP1251", url); // or UTF-8
```

Comment: спасибо. Проблема оказалась более глубокой.